# Specifying a specific module system when compiling Elm (vs. runtime checks)

Tags: elm, elm-make

Is there an option to let Elm know which module system you're targeting during compile time? E.g. something like a `--target` flag. I must admit that I haven't dug into [elm-make](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-make) that much.

Currently it seems that it only occurs during runtime:

- [elm-make/issues/50](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-make/issues/50)
- [src/Pipeline/Generate.hs](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-make/blob/3419cbc874710a8849a25754181cbf852119c177/src/Pipeline/Generate.hs#L201)

---

For my situation I'm:

- Using [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) which defines it's own `module` object *and* a global `window`.
- Only using Elm for a portion of the project (See [HTML interop](http://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/html.html)).

By default, the [compiled output](https://gist.github.com/trevorsenior/3d61d91ba9aaec00e3fa65f022329808#file-output-js-L13) defaults to exposing Elm on `module.exports`:

```
if (typeof define === "function" && define['amd'])
{
  define([], function() { return Elm; });
  return;
}

if (typeof module === "object")
{
  module['exports'] = Elm;
  return;
}

var globalElm = this['Elm'];
if (typeof globalElm === "undefined")
{
  this['Elm'] = Elm;
  return;
}
```

In debug tools:

[image: TronWM exposed in module.exports vs window]

Instead, I want it to expose it on `this`/`window` and not overwrite `module.exports` with the Elm object.

I was able to hack together a solution that abuses the AMD check:

```
    <script>
    window.define = (arr, fn) => {
        const Elm = fn();
        window.Elm = Elm;
    };
    window.define.amd = true;
    </script>
    <script src="build/tronwm.js"></script>
    <script>
    const node = document.getElementById('elm-render');
    const app = window.Elm.TronWM.embed(node);
    </script>
```

[image]

---

This works for now, but curious of alternate solutions if any.

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.18, no there is not. The Elm compiler does not know about details of JS Loaders etc.